# Can I make Lucene return an unlimited number of search results?

Tags: java, search, lucene, max, resultset

I am using Lucene 3.0.1 in a Java 5 environment.
I've been researching this issue a little bit, but the documentation hasn't given any direct answers.

Using the search method

```
TopFieldDocs    search(Weight weight, Filter filter, int nDocs, Sort sort)
```

I always need to provide a maximum number of search results **nDocs**.

What if I wanted to have all matching results? It feels like setting **nDocs** to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a kind of hacky way to do this (and would result in speed and memory performance drop?).

Anyone else who has any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [a search method](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort%29) that returns the top *n* hits for a query.

There are [other (more low-level) methods](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Collector%29) that do not have the limitation, and it says in the documentation that "applications should only use this if they need all of the matching documents. The high-level search API (search(Query, int)) is usually more efficient, as it skips non-high-scoring hits.".

So if you really need all documents, you can use the low-level API. I doubt that it makes a big difference in performance to passing a really high limit to the high-level API. If you need all documents (and there really are a lot of them), it is going to be slow either way, especially if sorting is involved.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, this was very helpful. I figured out another way to do it, which is to use searcher.maxDoc() as nDoc, but I figure that could also have an impact on the performance.

Comment: What is the difference between the low vs. high level APIs?