# Lucene only returning 100 results

Tags: lucene

i have increased the hits per page limit to a large integer. Even after that it returns only 100 results. Is there any way I can get all the results.

```
   int hitsPerPage = 5000000;
   IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index); 
   IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
   TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
  searcher.search(q, collector);
   int n= collector.getTotalHits();
   System.out.println(n);
   ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
   System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
```

Comment: You are printing the values of both `collector.getTotalHits` and `hits.length`.  Are they both showing the same value?

Comment: I tried using TopDocs as well. it also shows 100 whereas i am sure it is way more than 100. Yes both show the same value

Comment: Have you checked this question? It may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999998/can-i-make-lucene-return-an-unlimited-number-of-search-results